# UITableview which view this color belong to

Tags: swift, colors, tableview

I have a tableview below:

[image]

Where: the light grey color is tableview's. Now I want to change the little darker grey, which the red arrow points to. Which view does the little darker grey belong to?

My table view has `items.count` section, each section has 1 row, as below:

```
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return items.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        // build cells
    }
```

I tried to change `cell.backgroundColor` but it does not work.

Any ideas?

Regards

Comment: You covered up the image too much. I am having a hard time understanding which part of the table view you mean. Maybe show us a screenshot using the simulator?

Comment: While the app is running in the debugger, click the Debug View Hierarchy button in the debug bar. To know more about the view hierarchy refer the [apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/debugging_with_xcode/chapters/special_debugging_workflows.html)

Comment: Use screenshots in the future. Photos like this with blurred text over them is very hard to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The view is either **Header/Footer** of every `Section` in `UITableView`. Method `tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int)` will help you to customize it

Read [this](https://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/customizing-header-footer-table-view-ios8-swift) to customize

or set ***UITableView's style*** to `plain`

Comment: Yes, this is just a simply implementing `viewForHeaderInSection` and `viewForFooterInSection`. Thank you all for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

The arrow which you are pointing belongs to the UITableView background.

If you want to change it to little darker change

```
tableview.backgroundColor
```

Answer (score 0):

Add shadow in between every cell and choose the configuration from this method according to your need.

```
extension UIView {
    func addShadow(){
         self.clipsToBounds = true
         self.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
         self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.1
         self.layer.shadowRadius = 3.0
         self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(1.0, 1.0)
    }
}
//Just like that.
cell.addShadow()
```

Answer (score 0):

Like other's have said before, it's hard to tell because you've covered up so much of this image. But if none of the above answers work, try changing the tableview tint. And adjusting the insets.